# Web App in ASP.net published in Azure has errors, how could I see them?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm creating a web application using ASP.net, I have already published it to my azure portal, but now it is crashing and I don't know why. I just added one column to my model (and in database).

How can I fix it? Or how can I see the errors from azure server.

Also, I've seen my database didn't update the new column, how could I do that?

In postman, I get below error

`

> 500 Internal server error
> `

Comment: It was working fine, but when I updated it, it crashed. Thanks

Comment: I googled "turn on verbose errors in azure web app" and found a whole bunch of guides

Comment: @angelWoops, please try it with [log settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the next code:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

in your

> Global.asax

file project, and then you will see the erros when the server answers.